# How do I use custom project templates in Code::blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

In MS Visual studio I could make my own project and then save it as a custom template to use next time. Does anybody know how to do this in code blocks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX5lM.png

[image]