# How to modify the default initial main.cpp page in the C::B v13 IDE?

Tags: codeblocks

Instead of this initial snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713729/how-do-i-use-custom-project-templates-in-codeblocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, so I'll give three answers.

If you're referring to what opens when you open Code::Blocks itself, go to the `Settings` menu, then click `Environment`. Make sure you're in the `General Settings` section of the sidebar; change `On application start-up` to `Open blank workspace`.

If you're referring to what shows up when you create a new project, [@Blorgbeard's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713729/how-do-i-use-custom-project-templates-in-codeblocks) has a (slightly dated) picture showing how to create a new project template. Set up a project the way you want it, then open the `File` menu and click `Save project as template`.

If you're referring to what shows up when you create a new file in your project, go to the `Settings` menu, then click `Editor`. Scroll to the `Default code` section of the sidebar; whatever you enter here will be set as the default contents for any C++ source file (or any C++ header file) you create.

Comment: Thank you! I justed wanted to modify the initial page of the main.cpp each time you create a new project. But we have to do it with templates, I thought we could simply do it.

Answer (score 3):

For c++, edit Program Files ( or where you installed it ) \ `\CodeBlocks\share\CodeBlocks\templates\wizard\console\cpp\main.cpp`
and for c edit  `\CodeBlocks\share\CodeBlocks\templates\wizard\console\c\main.c`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where Codeblocks is installed and find the templates folder.

> Program Files / CodeBlocks / share / CodeBlocks / templates

You will find the **console-main-c** and **console-main-cpp** files there. Edit these files to change the default code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, you can find the default "main.cpp" file under:

> /usr/share/codeblocks/templates/wizard/console/cpp/

Just make sure you edit it with an admin privilege.