# Open new file with pre-written text in Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

Every time I create a new empty file in Code::Blocks, I want below code to be there in the file.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You should not include things under `<bits/..>` as those are library-specific implementation headers, i.e. in libstdc++.

Comment: Create a project and save it as a template.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The save as template is disabled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713729/how-do-i-use-custom-project-templates-in-codeblocks

Comment: You should not include files under the `bits` directory because they're not standard headers. What's not to understand?

Comment: @Rapptz ok. I misunderstood earlier.

Comment: @0x499602D2 This doesn't help. It creates a whole project every time I load the template. I just want to make a single file with above code written in it.